# What do parallel lines look like on the pseudosphere?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I know that because the pseudosphere is a model for hyperbolic geometry, there are infinitely many lines that can be drawn parallel to another given one through an external point.

However I'm struggling to figure out a pictorial representation for this.

Comment: Saw it late, answered now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an application of [Clairaut's Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut's_relation), you can work out quite explicitly what the geodesics on the pseudosphere are. The most useful form can be found in formula (6) on p. 258 of doCarmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* or in exercise 23 on p. 78 of my [differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). In particular, other than the meridians (the copies of the tractrix), we have curves that turn around the pseudosphere from the fat end to a parallel circle, hitting it tangentially. Choosing constants carefully, you can see that infinitely many of these will pass through a given point and miss a fixed meridian.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the "vertical" lines in [this image of the pseudosphere](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/Pseudosphere_700.gif&imgrefurl=http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudosphere.html&h=258&w=131&tbnid=KWv2jGWuzFR3HM:&vet=1&tbnh=160&tbnw=80&docid=EvpETpSEg0FAcM&client=safari&usg=__-SdjCcoQ_yfTn5XSatRdbC27IOw=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim9qvDlK_RAhWH2YMKHSS4DwgQ9QEIIDAA) are parallel to each other.

Comment: But, @Lee, that doesn't give infinitely many lines parallel to a given one through a given point!

Comment: Good point, I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

For pictorial representation: Two red asymptotic lines through P parallel to a blue line R from among infinitely many parallels are shown here again from [Wiki Hyp. Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry)

The situation in the plane  is given here from the Poincaré disk model. From out of many parallel lines a pair among them passing through P is marked red and either of them is parallel to to the blue line R. In the plane also Poincaré model also  such red line pairs parallel to a common parallel (not drawn) can be viewed.

In 3 space also I have shown a pair of red asymptotic lines through P  parallel  to the axis of symmetry R of a pseudosphere R.

Beltrami had shown and validated asymptotic lines of constant Gauss curvature $K$ pseudosphere as geodesic parallel lines (infinitely many parallel) pairs in three dimensional hyperbolic geometry. The parallel lines constitute a Chebyshev Net defined by Sine-Gordon equation with angle $2 \psi$ between pair of shown asymptotic lines:

$$ \dfrac{d^{2}\psi}{ds^2} = K \sin \psi \cos \psi $$

[image: Hyp Geodesics in R3]

These two *unique hyperbolic parallels* can be drawn on the central Beltrami and cone type Pseudospheres, constant negative K Kuen surfaces, Breather surfaces also.

Imho geodesic lines defined by Clairaut's Constant $( r \sin \psi$) on surfaces of revolution *do not* constitute unique parallel line as in case of hyperbolic geometry.

They are a *set of many* geodesics in *elliptic* geometry classified by Bernhard Riemann.

Answer (score 0):

Sketching hyperbolic geometry geodesic parallel lines as I understand them.

Two red asymptotic lines through P parallel to a blue line R from among infinitely many parallels are shown here again from [Wiki Hyp. Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry)

The situation in the plane  can be seen here in the Poincaré disk model. From out of many parallel lines a pair among them passing through P is marked red and either of them is parallel to to the blue line R. In the plane also Poincaré model also  such red line pairs parallel to a common parallel (not drawn) can be viewed.

In 3 space also I have shown a pair of red asymptotic lines through P  parallel  to the axis of symmetry R of a pseudosphere R.

Beltrami had shown and validated asymptotic lines of constant Gauss curvature $K$ pseudosphere as geodesic parallel lines (infinitely many parallel) pairs in three dimensional hyperbolic geometry. The parallel lines constitute a Chebyshev Net defined by Sine-Gordon equation with angle $2 \psi$ between pair of lines
$$ \psi^{''} = K \sin \psi \cos \psi $$

[image: Hyp Geodesics in R^3]

Imho geodesic lines defined by Clairaut's Constant $( r \sin \psi$) on surfaces of revolution *do not* constitute parallel line sets in hyperbolic geometry. They are geodesics in the other *elliptic* geometry categorized by Riemann.